# split of column from diffrent files

Tags: perl

I'd like to do my own script but I sticked fast. It is so trivial, but this is my second script.

I have a couple of files. In each, I have a 2 column, first with constant value (it is in the whole number of files), the third is diffrent. Each file is named as: occ_CXX, where XX is the number. (I don't need the second column) My idea:

1. split the whole number of files, whereas, the first column is common for all files, the second , third etc belongs to the files in order. (i use for it $my_files=$ARGV[0] - from this it takes only first column, and $my_pdb_files=$ARGV[1] - file, whithin the all files are listed), but I have to construct proper loop to read files and put the number in good order.
2. Moreover, I'd like to give a name of each column, which corespond to the number in its name (occ_CXX - I'm interested the CXX only).

The occ_CXX.dat file look like following:

```
  50000.000    1 291618
  50100.000    1 291618
  50200.000    0
  50300.000    1 115401
  50400.000    1 115401
```

Comment: Hello, Marta! Your idea sounds good  to me. Can you show us what you’ve tried so far implementing it, and where exactly you got stuck?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of the expected output. You can just build it from hand for the example input data you have shown. If you have already started and are stuck you can include that code as well.

Comment: I edited my question. Thank you in advance. I have an idea, but I have problem to write it.

Comment: How many 'occ_Cxx.dat' files are there? Are they in order as in the 'list.dat' file? Will all the files in the list file exist?

Comment: @ChrisCharley , It depend on my directory. I have around from 5 to 8 files. The fles are ordered increasing. But sth the numbers are omitted, e.g. I have files with numbers: 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11. But inside file, always started from 50000.

Comment: Will all the filenames be of the form `occ_C02.dat, occ_C03.dat, occ_C07.dat,  occ_C11.dat` or could they be `occ_C1.dat, occ_C7.dat`. And what is the purpose of `list.dat`. Will there be a `list.dat` file in every directory? Your `list.dat` above above only has 1 column.

Comment: @ChrisCharley , yes, you are correct, the form of files is the same. I created list to more "automatized" script. The script should read the list and then use step-by-step each file and from these files (occ_CXX.dat) read data and transfer third column to my new file. I thought it could be easier than read each document and add column inside new file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the description of your problem and some of the comments you gave, I think the code below may produce what you want.

I still don't understand how you access the files. I don't think the `list.dat` will make it easier. Just my opinion. I used glob instead to get the `occ_CXX.dat` files.

And I entered the directory on the command line. In the program, the directory name is `shifted` to the `$dir` variable.

My command line was

```
perl test.pl .
```

where the '**.**' is the name of the directory. I used the `dot` because the files are located in the same directory as my program. You would have to specify the directory or path to your files here instead of `dot` if your program is running from a different directory from where the files are located.

**Update:** Overlooked the matter of where you want to print your output file. That is, to what directory. Here, I just print the output file to the same directory as the input files.

**Update2:** Change

`for my $col1 (sort keys %data)`

to

`for my $col1 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %data)`

(updated my code to make this change)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = shift; # get directory from @ARGV (on the command line)

my @occ_files = sort by_number glob "$dir/occ_C*.dat";

my @headers = map /_(C\d+)/, @occ_files;

my %data;

for my $file (@occ_files) {
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file $!";

    $file =~ /_(C\d+)/;
    my $col_head = $1;

    while (<$fh>) {
        my ($col1, undef, $col3) = split;
        $data{$col1}{$col_head} = $col3 || '';
    }
    close $fh or die "Can't close $file $!";
}

my $format = "%-15s" . "%-10s" x (@headers-1) . "%s\n";

my $new_file = "$dir/occ_sub.dat";
open my $out, '>', $new_file or die "Can't open $new_file $!";

printf $out $format, '', @headers;

for my $col1 (sort {$a <=> $b} keys %data) {
    printf $out $format, $col1, @{ $data{$col1} }{@headers};    
}

sub by_number {
    my ($a_num) = $a =~ /_C(\d+)\.dat/;
    my ($b_num) = $b =~ /_C(\d+)\.dat/;
    $a_num <=> $b_num;
}
```

This created a file with this output (using your 2 sample input files):

```
               C01       C02
50000.000      291618    58902
50100.000      291618    58902
50200.000                58902
50300.000      115401    58902
50400.000      115401    58902
50500.000      115401    58902
50600.000      115401    58902
50700.000      115401    58902
50800.000      291618
50900.000      291618    58902
51000.000      291618    58902
51100.000      291618    58902
51200.000      291618    58902
51300.000      291618    58902
51400.000      291618    58902
51500.000      291618    58902
51600.000      291618    58902
51700.000      291618    58902
51800.000      291618
51900.000      291618    58902
52000.000      291618    58902
52100.000      291618    58902
52200.000      291618    58902
52300.000      291618    58902
52400.000      291618    58902
52500.000      291618    58902
52600.000      291618    58902
52700.000      291618
52800.000      291618    58902
52900.000      291618    58902
53000.000                58902
53100.000      291618    58902
53200.000      291618    58902
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! It works. Only when I have a numbers above 100000, it put them before 50000. How to change it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Marta Wisniewska see my update 2. This should be a  change you could fix on your own. Maybe take some time to learn more about the perl syntax and language  :).

Comment: thank you so much!!! I know it. I will learn more. Tjis is my plan for summer. I have to. By, anyway, thanks.